# Python - Local Time

Tags: python, date, datetime, utc, localtime

I have a dataframe that has entries like this, where the times are in UTC:

```
       start_date_time             timezone  
    1  2017-01-01 14:00:00  America/Los_Angeles   
    2  2017-01-01 14:00:00  America/Denver   
    3  2017-01-01 14:00:00  America/Phoenix   
    4  2017-01-01 14:30:00  America/Los_Angeles   
    5  2017-01-01 14:30:00  America/Los_Angeles
```

I need to be able to group by date (local date, not UTC date) and I need to be able to create indicators for whether the event happened between certain times (local times, not UTC times).

I have successfully done the above in R by:

- Creating a time variable in each of the timezones
- Converting those to strings
- Pulling each of the string date/time variables into one column, which one I pull depends on the appropriate timezone
- Then, splitting that column to get a string date column and a string time column

I can then convert everything back to datetime objects for comparisons. e.g. now I can say if something happened between 2 and 3pm and it will correctly identify everything that happened between 2 and 3pm locally.

I have tried a bunch in python and have the dates as

```
    2017-01-02 04:30:00-08:00
```

but I can't figure out how to go from there to

```
    2017-01-01 20:30:00
```

Thanks!

Comment: That would be too easy if you post your code in question.

Comment: Look at the DateTime package in Python.  Look for the time zone controls.  Do your best to write code to solve it; post again if you run into difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is incorrect. Your timezone is eight hours behind UTC, which means you need to *add* eight hours to 4:30AM which is 12:30PM UTC time.

The `datetime` object function `astimezone(...)` will do the conversion for you. For ease of use, I recommend [pytz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz).

However in pure python:

```
import datetime as dt
local_tz = dt.timezone(dt.timedelta(hours=-8))
utc = dt.timezone.utc
d = dt.datetime(2017, 1, 2, 4, 30, 0, 0, local_tz)
print(d, d.astimezone(utc))
```

Will print:

```
2017-01-02 04:30:00-08:00 2017-01-02 12:30:00+00:00
```

Here's an example using pytz to lookup time zones:

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

dates = [("2017-01-01 14:00:00",  "America/Los_Angeles"),
         ("2017-01-01 14:00:00",  "America/Denver"),   
         ("2017-01-01 14:00:00",  "America/Phoenix"),
         ("2017-01-01 14:30:00",  "America/Los_Angeles"),   
        ]

for d, tz_str in dates:
    start = dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    start = start.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(tz_str)  # convert to desired timezone
    print(start, local_tz.zone, "\t", start.astimezone(local_tz))
```

This produces:

```
2017-01-01 14:00:00+00:00 America/Los_Angeles    2017-01-01 06:00:00-08:00
2017-01-01 14:00:00+00:00 America/Denver         2017-01-01 07:00:00-07:00
2017-01-01 14:00:00+00:00 America/Phoenix        2017-01-01 07:00:00-07:00
2017-01-01 14:30:00+00:00 America/Los_Angeles    2017-01-01 06:30:00-08:00
```